# Vim - only change cursor on manual mode switch?

Tags: vim

Currently I have vim configured to change the cursor shape based on the mode I'm in, and it works correctly (code below).  My problem is that I have some plugins that run in insert mode but briefly return to normal mode to execute (e.g. UltiSnips and AutoPairs).  When they briefly return to normal mode, the cursor flips to a block for a moment before returning to a bar, causing a strange and distracting flashing effect.  Is there any way to only trigger cursor shape switches when I manually switch modes and not when changed by script?  Or some other clever hack to address this issue?

```
if empty($TMUX)
  let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7" " Vertical bar in insert mode
  let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7" " Block in normal mode
  let &t_SR = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=2\x7" " Underline in replace mode
else
  let &t_SI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7\<Esc>\\"
  let &t_EI = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7\<Esc>\\"
  let &t_SR = "\<Esc>Ptmux;\<Esc>\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=2\x7\<Esc>\\"
endif
```

Comment: If you want to have control on that just use mappings in different modes.

Comment: I would strongly prefer not to have to hit a special key sequence every time I hop in and out of insert mode, and I really like the visual change so I don't want to sacrifice having it.  I want to have my cake and eat it too.